# Sylius : How to filter products by attributes in Sylius?

Tags: sylius

Someone can tell me how to filter products by attributes in Sylius. For example I have an attribute color. And I want to get all product they are white.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a custom method in your product repository:

```
public function findByAttribute($attributeName, $value) 
{
    return $this->getQueryBuilder()
        ->join($this->getAlias() . '.attributes', 'av')
        ->join('av.attribute', 'a')
        ->where('av.value = :value')
        ->andWhere('a.name = :attributeName')
        ->setParameter('attributeName', $attributeName)
        ->setParameter('value', $value)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Sylius version 1.x

```
public function findAttributeByChannel(ChannelInterface $channel, string $locale, int $count, int $attributeId): array
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->addSelect('translation')
        ->innerJoin('o.translations', 'translation', 'WITH', 'translation.locale = :locale')
        ->innerJoin('o.attributes', 'attribute')
        ->andWhere('attribute.attribute = :attribute_id')
        ->andWhere(':channel MEMBER OF o.channels')
        ->andWhere('o.enabled = true')
        ->addOrderBy('o.createdAt', 'DESC')
        ->setParameter('channel', $channel)
        ->setParameter('locale', $locale)
        ->setParameter('attribute_id', $attributeId)
        ->setMaxResults($count)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```